# How do I maintain two different alignments, one for each sub-element, in my ItemTemplate element?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a pretty straightforward ASP.NET website. I'm pulling all my data for the code from a database. I'm trying to figure out why when I change my text size, it takes effect, but if I change the text-align property, it doesn't take effect. Here's the code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" 
    runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="picTableStyle"
    DataKeyField="ID">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="picTableStyle"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <br /><br />
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" +
                 Eval("Image") %>' /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" class="picCaptionStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                 Eval("Caption") %>' /></td>

        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="picTitleStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                 Eval("PicTitle") %>' /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TravelDate", 
                 "{0:MMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") %>' /><br /><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PicText") %>' />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Here is the pertinent section in my .css file:

```
    .picCaptionStyle
    {
        font-family:Century;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:8pt;
    }
    .picTitleStyle
    {
        font-family:Agency FB;
        text-align:left;
        font-size:14pt;
        color:Red;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .picTableStyle
    {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

It only ever centers when I change the .picTableStyle rule to text-align:center; and leave it out on the other rules. But of course, it centers all the text in my ItemTemplate. I want to center the caption for the picture on the picture, but keep the text left.

Answer (score 0):

take the labels into spans and provide style into span. Maybe this will help

Comment: Hey NetTrapper, tried it and it didn't work. I appreciate the suggestion though. It seems crazy to me that when I change it in the parent style rule, it moves all the text. But if I try to change in the rule specifically pertaining to the element in question, it doesn't take effect.